# improve python elasticsearch performance

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

i am new in python and Elasticsearch
i write a python code that read data from very large json file and index some attributes in Elasricsearch.

```
import elasticsearch
import json
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()  # use default of localhost, port 9200
with open('j.json') as f:
    n=0
    for line in f:
        try:
            j_content = json.loads(line)
            event_type = j_content['6000000']
            device_id = j_content['6500048']
            raw_event_msg= j_content['6000012']
            event_id = j_content["0"]
            body = {
                '6000000': str(event_type),
                '6500048': str(device_id),
                '6000012': str(raw_event_msg),
                '6000014': str(event_id),
            }
            n=n+1
            es.index(index='coredb', doc_type='json_data', body=body)
        except:
            pass
```

but it's too slow and i have many free hardware resources. how can i improve performance of code with multi thread or bulk ?

Comment: As you have a for loop, the multi threading is kind of a straightforward answer, given that your Elastic cluster can handle a heavier load. (Instead of multi threading, I'd suggest you use multiprocessing in Python, mainly because of the GIL). Then, I'd suggest you have a look at this article which gives good tips to increase the indexing speed: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html

Comment: You should use the [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/docs-bulk.html) instead of single document indexing within the python client, in comnbination with the [bulk helpers](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into using Elasticsearch `helpers`, one in particular called `bulk`, seems you are aware of it, so instead of Elasticsearch setting the data to the index on every loop, collect the results in a list, and then once that list reaches a certain length, use the `bulk` function, and this dramatically increases performance.

You can see a rough idea with the following example; I had a very large text file, with 72873471 lines, efficiently calculated from the command line with `wc -l big-file.txt`, and then, using the same method you posted, resulted in an estimated ETA of 10 days

```
# Slow Method ~ 10 days
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import progressbar # pip3 install progressbar2
import re
es = Elasticsearch()
file = open("/path/to/big-file.txt")
with progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=72873471) as bar:
    for idx, line in enumerate(file):
        bar.update(idx)
        clean = re.sub("\n","",line).lstrip().rstrip()
        doc = {'tag1': clean, "tag2": "some extra data"}
        es.index(index="my_index", doc_type='index_type', body=doc)
```

Now importing helpers from Elasticsearch, cut that time down to 3.5 hours:

```
# Fast Method ~ 3.5 hours
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import progressbar # pip3 install progressbar2
import re
es = Elasticsearch()
with progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=72873471) as bar:
actions = []
file = open("/path/to/big-file.txt")
for idx, line in enumerate(file):
    bar.update(idx)
    if len(actions) > 10000:
        helpers.bulk(es, actions)
        actions = []
    clean = re.sub("\n","",line).lstrip().rstrip()
    actions.append({
        "_index": "my_index", # The index on Elasticsearch
        "_type": "index_type", # The document type
        "_source": {'tag1': clean, "tag2": "some extra data"}
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want it is called [Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)  ;)

You can speed up your code up to 20x for sure only enabling static typing to your variables.

The code bellow should go into cython, give it a try, you'll see:

```
try:
    j_content = json.loads(line)       # Here you might want to work with cython structs.
                                       # I can see you have a json per line, so it should be easy
    event_type = j_content['6000000']
    device_id = j_content['6500048']
    raw_event_msg= j_content['6000012']
    event_id = j_content["0"]
    body = {
        '6000000': str(event_type),
        '6500048': str(device_id),
        '6000012': str(raw_event_msg),
        '6000014': str(event_id),
    }
    n=n+1
```

Comment: The answer is not related to the original question, as it does not mention how to use threads or bulk api. Also, dictionary initialization is barely a problem in comparison with multiple api calls over network.

Comment: @PyGuy, while is true my answer does not mention how to use treads or bulk api (or asyncIO or trio), it is indeed **related** the the question that is about performance. And for sure speeding up dictionary initialization would improve performance a lot.